# Selenium Webdriver Logging

Tags: java, selenium, logging, selenium-webdriver, slf4j

I am using selenium-server and phantomjsdriver in a java application.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.44.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

**This generates 3 different kinds of output on my console**

1. org.slf4j.Logger application logs, no log settings yet
2. selenium webdriver logs
3. phantomJS output?

**Now the questions are**

1. How do I make Selenium log to slf4j? (Or any other Logger)
2. Have all messages in the same format
3. Is it possible to write the phantomJS / Selenium logs into a seperate file?

**Example output below**

```
2232 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO com.opendi.util.selenium.service.PhantomJsService - New PhantomJS instance
Oct 07, 2015 10:14:50 AM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: executable: /home/michel/github/work/screencapture/bin/amd64/phantomjs
Oct 07, 2015 10:14:50 AM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: port: 11710
Oct 07, 2015 10:14:50 AM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: arguments: [--webdriver=11710]
2306 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO com.opendi.util.selenium.service.PhantomJsService - New PhantomJS instance
Oct 07, 2015 10:14:50 AM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: executable: /home/michel/github/work/screencapture/bin/amd64/phantomjs
Oct 07, 2015 10:14:50 AM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: port: 18873
Oct 07, 2015 10:14:50 AM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: arguments: [--webdriver=18873]
Oct 07, 2015 10:14:50 AM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: environment: {}
Oct 07, 2015 10:14:50 AM org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriverService <init>
INFO: environment: {}
[INFO  - 2015-10-07T08:14:50.392Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 18873
[INFO  - 2015-10-07T08:14:50.421Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 11710
```

Some help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Sorry no. Can’t wrap my head around java logging logic. I ended up writing every stderr/stdout output into files using bash redirection - in my case it was running on a console

Answer (score 0):

What is your logger implementation in your application I mean for example I use some time log4j and put log4j.properties on the class path and define the below

> log4j.rootLogger=INFO,R,STDOUT
>   log4j.appender.STDOUT=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
>   log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>   log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}
>   %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
>
> log4j.appender.R.File=${user.home}/mylogFile.log
>
> log4j.logger.org.openqa.selenium=INFO, R